# How to find out which distribution package provides a given library

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, libraries, apt

I am looking for a way to find for a given LDFLAG, like `-lcryptopp`, the distribution package that provides me with that that library, like `libcrypto++-dev` on Debian/Ubuntu.

So far, I have looked up these libraries by hand and common sense, and using e.g. `aptitude search`, `apt-file search`and Google.

However, now I am building a VM in which I want to test-compile [all Haskell community packages](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html), and those depend on more C libraries than I can look up by hand.

**How would you, somewhat reliably, look up the package by its linking name?**

I'm working on Debian-based systems, but also interested in solutions for other distributions. Anything that will make this job easier is appreciated, be it a web service, some tool or database, or smart knowledge about certain files are named.

I am aware that this cannot be fully automated, since two different packages can technically provide libraries with the same name. I'm fine with something that can find *most* of the packages.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the packages installed on a system:

```
  for pc in $(find /usr/lib/pkgconfig/ ${PKG_CONFIG_PATH//:/ } -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pc"); do
      printf "$pc " 
      pp=${pc/#*\/} 
      pp=${pp/%.pc/}
      pkg-config --modversion --libs ${pp}
      printf "\n"
  done
```

This calls `pkg-config` with every installed `.pc` file on your system, it queries the libraries each packages uses and the library path required (which are the `-l` and `-L` flags respectively, as passed to the compiler/linker). This is more or less what the typical `configure` script does (when you're off making coffee or something more productive than watching lines scroll by).

There are also likely to be a few stragglers which do not use `pkg-config`, and instead install a `-config` script:

```
for pkg in $(find ${PATH//:/ } -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*-config"); do 
    printf "$pkg " 
    $pkg --version --libs
    printf "\n"
done
```

You'll still need to do a bit of grep-ing to find exactly what you're looking for, since the output of the above is what the package needs to pass to the compiler *it will include the packages own dependencies too*. The library/libraries that the package itself provides tend to be listed first though, e.g.

```
/usr/bin/xine-config 1.1.7
-L/usr/lib -lxine -lz -lresolv -lnsl -pthread -lrt
           ^^^^^^
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/flac.pc 1.2.1
-L/usr/local/lib -lFLAC -lm  
                 ^^^^^^
```

Once you have the `.pc` file or the `-config` file identified, confirm the package with `dpkg`:

```
 dpkg -S /usr/lib/pkgconfig/libxml-2.0.pc
 libxml2-dev: /usr/lib/pkgconfig/libxml-2.0.pc
```

or the local package manager equivalent, e.g. `rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/lib/pkgconfig/libxml-2.0.pc`

Answer (score 1):

You can list the packages of all installed header files by running:

```
find / -name '*.h' | xargs -i apt-file search {}
```

This will take a long time, but you'll have a complete list of all libraries installed on your system. You can also list **all** .h files within **all** packages:

```
apt-file search --regexp '\.h$'
```